# AWSCLI command to get object - object id/x-amz-id-2 AND List/Search object having given object id / x-amz-id-2

Tags: object, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, object-storage

AWSCLI command to get object x-amz-id-2 AND List object having given **object id / x-amz-id-2**

Please advice which AWSCLI we can use to

1. Get **object id / x-amz-id-2** of single/multiple objects under a bucket
2. Search and list object of ECS bucket having given **object id / x-amz-id-2**

Tried

- s3api head-object
- s3api get-object-tagging
- s3api list-objects-v2
  But neither of these worked and the s3api head-object is showing below information. But, still not able to get **x-amz-id-2** of objects.

Output of s3api head-object for single object as for this sub-command, we need to supply object path as key as its mandatory ->

```
{
    "LastModified": "2024-03-05T22:50:58+00:00",
    "ContentLength": 10365860,
    "ETag": "\"f10b2d17dc*******4d12e141378f50\"",
    "VersionId": "17096******12",
    "ContentType": "application/octet-stream",
    "Metadata": {}
}
```

If running this along with --debug then it has the response header which contains **x-amz-id-2** and other relevant key-values but not sure how to get **x-amz-id-2** only using any awscli command.

Extract of s3api head-object with --debug ->

```
2024-03-09 00:00:46,830 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'Date': 'Fri, 08 Mar 2024 18:30:46 GMT', 'Server': '******.0', 'x-amz-request-id': '80*****b:18d*****60b:e***9:7*c', 'x-amz-id-2': '2e*******************208d6f4589bfce4a780492c534f5c1c105e4d3ab62', 'x-amz-version-id': '17096******12', 'ETag': '"f10b2d17dc*******4d12e141378f50"', 'Last-Modified': 'Tue, 05 Mar 2024 22:50:58 GMT', 'x-emc-mtime': '17096******12', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Content-Length': '10365860'}
```

Below snap is from S3 Browser showing all these information under Headers tab: -
[image]

Comment: x-amz-id-2 and x-amz-request-id are only useful if Amazon support asks for them, they're not necessarily unique or consistent for a given object.

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward.... However, Storage Vendor like dell for ecs, aws s3 etc. providing the object id only to check the object and so looking a way to search bucket for received object id / x-amz-id-2 to get the information of actual object.... Please advice if any way you know for this....Thanks!!

Comment: If no direct way then, please advice if we can query the debug output to get only required key value... In this case, it's x-amz-id-2 exists under Response headers of debug output.. Thanks!